# Manually splitting projection queries and reassembling them client side

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I have a seemingly horridly complex query that EF core is struggling with.
It executes it (with asSplitQuery) but I suspect its not splitting it in a completely sensible way.

In the old days of datasets you would write a projection of your database into each datatable, and then let the dataset manage the relationships between them.

Is there an EF equivalent? (for projected values) or do people actually project EF data into datasets?

Comment: When query is splitted, multiple SQL are executed when loading collections. Have you analyzed generated SQL? Anyway, you can load everything splitted by yourself.

Comment: how do i analyse the SQL? via the logging?

Comment: I'm projecting...so I'd like to create split queries that project

Comment: Yes analyze logs. Or use SQL Server Profiler or other tools according to DataProvider.

Comment: its oracle (sadly)

Comment: The few times I've looked at split queries, the splitting seemed ideal. All 1:M relations were retrieved in separate queries, while all 1:1 relations were retrieved in a single wide query. No duplicated retrievals.

Comment: maybe....if i compare it with datasets, then i would design the output format (basically in terms of N tables), create N queries that retrieve the information required (often not simple involving some trade offs) and then run the N queries into the N tables, I find it hard to believe that split queries will do it as efficiently, especially the trade offs, e.g. overfetching some data to merge M queries into 1.